# How to create a new variable conditioning on another variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

Consider the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 v1=c(2020,2020,2021,2021,2022),
                 v2=c(12,5,66,17,17))
```

I need the output of the form (just averaging `v2` based on `v1`):

```
id  v1     v2   avg_by_yr
 1  2020   12    8.5
 2  2020    5    8.5
 3  2021   66    41.5
 4  2021   17    41.5
 5  2022   17     17
```

Thanks!

Comment: With `dplyr`, `df %>% group_by(v1) %>% mutate(avg_by_yr = mean(v2))`

Comment: Using `base`, `within(df, avg_by_yr <- ave(v2, v1))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks. Although the second works, the first gives me a different output.

Comment: What do you mean about the different output?

Comment: The value of the newly created variable is constant (which is 23.4 on my pc).

Comment: I guess there is a conflict of packages because you load `plyr` after `dplyr`. You can fix it by specifying the package name, i.e. `df %>% group_by(v1) %>% dplyr::mutate(avg_by_yr = mean(v2))`

Comment: You're right. I loaded the two packages at the same time. Now fixed. Thanks a lot!